# Is it possible to render map tiles with a Nominatim PostGIS database?

Tags: openstreetmap, database, nominatim

I've imported a OSM database using Nominatim's setup.php. Is it possible to use some software to render the tiles using that database, or do I have to re-import in a different database for Mapnik and similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to recycle the database, as both tools do very different tasks and therefore they create [very specific datastructures](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Databases) to run nice and smooth.

Please import another time your DB dump for mapnik, as explained here: www.switch2osm.org

Comment: If you use different database names, you can use mapnik and nominatim at the same time. But you still have to import the data twice.